# Stop iAd auto layout

Tags: ios, swift2, iad

I've been using SpriteKit and Swift 2 to create a game, and I've ran into some issues when adding an iAd banner.

Currently, I have the iAd view in the storyboard that I've connected to an outlet. I basically only have the code to set up then show and hide the ad when necessary, the mains parts are below.

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
self.topAdBanner?.delegate = self
self.topAdBanner?.hidden = true



func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.topAdBanner?.hidden = false
}
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.topAdBanner?.hidden = true
}
```

Problems

- iAd changes its position. In the storyboard, I have it constrained to the top. However, when the app runs the Ad forces itself to the bottom of the screen. I want it to stay at the top.
- When the Ad transitions or shows after being hidden, it resizes the SpriteKit SKView and it looks really bad. Is there a way to make it sit on top of the SKView and not effect it?

I've tried some different things but they always have errors which makes me believe that Swift 2 has changed how this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the banners manually if you dont want the views to resize.

```
topBannerAd = AdBannerView(...
topBannerAd.delegate = self
topBannerAd.center = ....
```

Good tutorials are these

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1a-D3h3PSk

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/18/2/iad-in-10-minutes

You can also check out my ads helper I posted on github. Its mainly for spritekit but can be used for regular apps as well.

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper